# PHP strpos not working

Tags: php, strpos

I've always had problems with strpos, I understand the num v. boolean issue, but I can NOT get this working. The $cur_key value is something like "page=>name"...

```
$pos = strpos($cur_key, "=>");
if ($pos !== false) {
   $mod = explode("=>",$cur_key);
   $path = $mod[0];
   $param = $mod[1];                                
}else{
   $path = $cur_key;
}
```

If it's in there it should split it into the two values but no matter what I try it's always just returning the original value...

Comment: Is it possible that the `>` is being HTML encoded into, say `&gt;`?

Comment: so path is always returning the original value? then there is no '=>' in your $cur_key varaiable.
I tested your code with the string you gave 'page=>name' and everything is working, what is the problem here?

Comment: Your code works correctly: http://codepad.viper-7.com/lN4pWV. Can you find an example that is not working ?

Comment: +1 learned something - '!==' operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mod = explode('=>',$cur_key);
$path=$mod[0];
if (sizeof($mod)>1) $param=$mod[1]; else $param='';
```