# php strpos not evaluating correctly?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I am having a similar issue to this post: [PHP strpos not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702153/php-strpos-not-working), but not quite.

Here is my situation (from a CodeIgniter application):

```
$_submit = strtolower($this->input->post('form-submit'));

if(strpos('save', $_submit) !== FALSE){
    // we have to save our post data to the db
}
if(strpos('next'), $_submit) !== FALSE){
    // we have to get the next record from the db
}
```

The problem is, neither of these actually fire, despite form-submit containing one, or both of those values. The values form-submit receives are: 'save', 'save-next', and 'skip-next' (which I have confirmed by looking at the post data as it comes in). Now for the real head scratcher, I also have this line in the same code chunk:

```
if ($_submit === 'add-comment'){
    //do something
}
```

And that works perfectly fine. So === is working as expected, but !== is not?

Comment: Can we assume that your second condition is a typo and not the actual code?

Comment: it's a string so use 'strtolower($this->input->post('form-submit'))'

Comment: Please accept it as answer also if my answer helps you in solving your issue.........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving arguments wrong to the strpos function.......

```
$submit = strtolower($this->input->post('form-submit'));

if(strpos($submit,'save') !== FALSE){
    // we have to save our post data to the db
}
if(strpos($submit,'next') !== FALSE){
    // we have to get the next record from the db
}
```

Please look into the [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function in php.net manual....first argument is full string and second one is key string

You can find a small [example](http://eval.in/10552) here also.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an noob now. I had looked at it, but apparently not closely enough. Thanks.

Comment: hey i am looking for some freelance work in PHP or CodeIgniter based also.

Answer (score 2):

Your arguments to `strpos` are the wrong way round: as [the manual states](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) it is `strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle )`. In your code you are looking for the needle `$_submit` in the haystack `'save'`.

So `if(strpos($_submit, 'save') !== FALSE)`

[Of course, when testing `'save'` against `'save'`, either way around will work, which is probably what confused you.]

Comment: Thanks, I feel like a noob. Apparently I can't read all that well.

Comment: Heh, we've all done it. Particularly with PHP, which has a tendency not to be very consistent in its argument order...

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. I was like "I know it's needle then haystack" and then I looked again, and this time it's haystack/needle. AGH!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use switch instead of multiple if conditions.

```
$_submit = strtolower($this->input->post('form-submit'));

switch($_submit) {
    case 'save':
    case 'save-comment': // example for different spelling but same action...
         // we have to save our post data to the db
    break;
    case 'next':
         // we have to get the next record from the db
    break;
    case 'add-comment':
         // we have to save our post data to the db
    break;
    default:
        die('Unknown parameter value');
    break;
}
```

Comment: Usually I would, time is short so I'm just doing the quickest solution for now. When I go back and re-factor, then I will break stuff out more. Thanks for the input!